# Jquery File Upload - $_FILES array empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

Using Jquery File Upload. It's 'working' and uploading images & displaying the thumbs. However when I Submit the form in the handler if I dump $_FILES there's nothing there.

I'm basically using the Basic Plus example with autoUpload set to false. I was hoping that I would be able to use this to have users select multiple images. Then have them uploaded once the form was submitted and handle them basically the same way I would handle them if I had X number of file upload buttons on a page.

Uploading them using autoUpload=TRUE also works as well. I tried that and didn't see anything in POST or FILES either.

Comments to get either method working would be great.

Here's my js below.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
    // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
    // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
    // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
        .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
    previewMaxWidth: 100,
    previewMaxHeight: 100,
    previewCrop: true
}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        var node = $('<p/>')
                .append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
        node.appendTo(data.context);
    });
}).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
    var index = data.index,
        file = data.files[index],
        node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
    if (file.preview) {
        node
            .prepend('<br>')
            .prepend(file.preview);
    }
    if (file.error) {
        node
            .append('<br>')
            .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
    }
    if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
        data.context.find('button')
            .text('Upload')
            .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
    }
}).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
        'width',
        progress + '%'
    );
}).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
        if (file.url) {
            var link = $('<a>')
                .attr('target', '_blank')
                .prop('href', file.url);
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .wrap(link);
        } else if (file.error) {
            var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .append('<br>')
                .append(error);
        }
    });
}).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('File upload failed.');
        $(data.context.children()[index])
            .append('<br>')
            .append(error);
    });
}).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
    .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
```

Here's my html

```
<form action="/submit_form" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-horizontal review-validate-form" id="review-form" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"><div style="display:none">
```

```
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="required control-label" for="first_name">Comments <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="10" class="span8 required" id="comments" ></textarea>             </div>
        </div>



        <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <span>Add files...</span>
    <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
</span>
<br>
<br>
<!-- The global progress bar -->
<div id="progress" class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
</div>
<!-- The container for the uploaded files -->
<div id="files" class="files"></div>
<br>



        <div class="form-actions" style="">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Review" name="submitReview" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
        </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the set correct datatype 
  dataType: 'json',
to multipart form data 
you cant set $_FILES variable with data type json attribute

Comment: if you want to get files with $_FILES variable via PHP, you need to set dataType multipart/form-data, you can't get files with $_FILES variable with dataType json

Comment: Are you sure? I get files with $_FILES variable via PHP while dataType is json. I think multipart/form-data is related with an other property and its default value is already multipart/form-data. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Got it to work by appending a hidden input for each file uploaded so that I can process them and add them to the database after the form is submitted.

I feel like there should be something built in already to handle this but for now this works.

Added a filesHidden div to hold the hidden fields.

```
<div id="files" class="files"></div>
```

Then updated the js to which appends a hidden input with filename to pass along to my form handler so I can link up the images with the form submission.

```
}).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            if (file.url) {
                $( "#filesHidden" ).append( '<input type="hidden" name="images[]" value="' + file.name + '">' );
            } else if (file.error) {
                var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(error);
            }
    });
        }
```

Full Example Below (Requested in comments below). Note my example also adds a title text box to each uploaded image.

```
var url = '/js/fileUpload/server/php/';
uploadButton = $('<button/>')
 .addClass('btn btn-primary')
 .prop('disabled', true)
 .text('Processing...')
 .on('click', function () {
     var $this = $(this),
         data = $this.data();
     $this
         .off('click')
         .text('Abort')
         .on('click', function () {
             $this.remove();
             data.abort();
         });
     data.submit().always(function () {
         $this.remove();
     });
 });

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: true,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
    // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
    // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
    // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
        .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
    previewMaxWidth: 100,
    previewMaxHeight: 100,
    previewCrop: true
}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
}).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
    var index = data.index,
        file = data.files[index],
        node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
    if (file.preview) {
        var node = $('<p/>')
        .append('<br /><strong>Description</strong>: <input type="text" name="title[]" value="">');
        node.appendTo(data.context);

        node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
        node
            .prepend('<br>')
            .prepend(file.preview);
    }
    if (file.error) {
        alert(file.error);
    }
    if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
        data.context.find('button')
            .text('Upload')
            .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
    }
}).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
        'width',
        progress + '%'
    );
}).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
        if (file.url) {
            $( "#filesHidden" ).append( '<input type="hidden" name="images[]" value="' + file.name + '">' );
        } else if (file.error) {
            var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .append('<br>')
                .append(error);
        }
    });
}).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('File upload failed.');
        $(data.context.children()[index])
            .append('<br>')
            .append(error);
    });
}).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
    .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
```

Comment: Would it be possible to see the whole solution? Dealing with the same problem. Who handles file upload on serve side in your case, php?

Comment: Sure. php handles the file upload in my case. After form submit I loop through the hidden images array and move files from the default location. And I just have a script to periodically clear out that default folder of any old files which happens when someone uploads but doesn't submit.

Comment: @krizajB - Added full example into my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem time ago, my solution was to increase post data size data and max size per file in php.ini:

```
post_max_size=15M
upload_max_filesize=15M
```