# Jquery File Upload collecting the file from the form once the post has been submitted

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the jQuery-File-Upload for the first time.

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html

The file upload is contained inside a form that has other input fields.

When the form is submitted I would simply like to collect the name of the files that have been uploaded  and perhaps location.

I am collecting the other variables like so,

```
if(isset($_GET['sub_btn'])){
    $first_name = isset($_GET["firstname"]) ? $_GET["firstname"] : "";
 }
```

But I cannot get the files that are uploaded to the server/php/files folder to appear in the $_GET or the $_POST.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The [`$.FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) array should contain what you're searching for.

Comment: I have this in my code,

print '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
die();

and that brings back the following;

Array
(
    [firstname] => Dave
)
Array
(
)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the file on the server and set the date via POSt u can get them with `$_FILES` and not with POST or GET

Tiny example:

```
<?php
$output_dir = "uploads/";
if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
$ret = array();

$error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
//You need to handle  both cases
//If Any browser does not support serializing of multiple files using FormData() 
if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]["name"])) //single file
{
    $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);
    $ret[]= $fileName;
}
else  //Multiple files, file[]
{
  $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
  for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
  {
    $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$fileName);
    $ret[]= $fileName;
  }

}
echo json_encode($ret);
}
?>
```

JS:

```
$("#multipleupload").uploadFile({
   url:"http://hayageek.com/examples/jquery/ajax-multiple-file-upload/upload.php",
   multiple:true,
   fileName:"myfile"
 });
```

[Source](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys, I actually found a solution here.

[Jquery File Upload - $_FILES array empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862937/jquery-file-upload-files-array-empty)